# copying html from another website in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I copy the source code from a website (with javascript)? I want to copy the text that is showing the temperature from this website: http://www.accuweather.com/
I want to copy only the number that is displaying the temperature. Is there a way of copying that exact line from source code on the website? I heard about html scraping. if not javascript, what would be simplest way of doing it? Just copying the temeprature, and displaying it on my webpage.

Comment: Find an api....

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you should try to learn who to use an API. Accuweather do provide an API to retrieve this data you can have more info here : http://developer.accuweather.com/. By using the API you'll be able to collect the data from Accuweather and use it in your JS files.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against getting that information by trying to parse the temperature text out of the actual HTML on their website.  All they have to do is change the HTML of their site around, and your code will break without warning.  Instead you would be better off finding a free web service that you can call from your code to get the temperature.

Comment: Just to inform you that the accuweather API is a paid service.

Comment: What do you want this for ? a temporary task (like a homework or something) or a permanent site ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira i started learning html, javascript, the usual web stuff.i am trying to make my own website, programming in notepad and saving as html. i already have buttons, made some easy scripts, made a date and time display, and now i thought it would be easy taking some code from a website and displaying it. i dont even know what to learn from here i saw something with JSONs and web scraping but theres noone to redirect me in the right way. i thought it would be simple task just to copy it so i can see the temperature on my web page. :)

Comment: The only "sane" way (if you agree this is sane compared to an API call) would be to use a server to grab the source (periodically...), parse it with a DOM parser, and extract the data from that element. Save that somewhere and use it in your site.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a lot of websites' terms of service specifically prohibit scraping data from their pages (especially when they offer a paid API).

Answer (score 0):

Well the way you could do something like that in a simple way by loading the site into a hidden HTML element via AJAX and then search DOM for the element you want.

There is also a jQuery command that allows that directly. It would be something like:

```
<div id='temp'></div>
<script>
    $('div#temp').load('https://www.accuweather.com/ #popular-locations-ul .large-temp', { limit: 1 });
</script>
```

`#popular-locations-ul .large-temp` is a css locator for the specific elements that contain the temperature.

However for some time web has a security feature called CORS. To be able to load something from one site via AJAX, the target site has to allow CORS headers explicitly. In the case of this particular site, CORS headers aren't present in the site configuration, so that means that any connection that tries to load something via AJAX won't be allowed.

You can only use a command like the above mentioned in a site you control and that you specify to allow CORS headers or in a site who already has this specification.

But as people have told you that's not a good thing from the start due to web sites impermanent nature. Things change a lot. So even if you could get a value in the way I mentioned from some other site, sometime later, the site would change and your code would be broken.

The reason I answered is because you are just learning and need guidance and not trying to do 'serious work'. Serious work would be using an API as people told you.

An web api is a special url you access (something like https://www.accuweather.com:1234/api/temperature/somecity) normally with some kind of security and that responds with the result you need for the function you want. For this kind service CORS is allowed because you are accessing in a secure and 'official' way.

Hope I clarified a bit.